# What step am I missing to get my 2.6 ARM kernel running in QEMU?

Tags: linux, kernel, qemu, initramfs, arch-arm

I am trying to cross-compile and boot a Linux 2.6 kernel for ARM using QEMU. I have basically followed the same instructions that are included in seemingly *every single tutorial* on the topic.

Specifically:

1. Download and compile kernel

   ```
   $ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- versatile_defconfig
   $ #Disabled loadable modules and enabled initramfs
   $ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- all
   ```
2. Compile Busybox

   ```
   $ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- arm
   $ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- install
   ```
3. Create cpio archive from Busybox `_install` directory

   ```
   $ cd $BUSYBOX/_install
   $ find . | cpio -o -Hnewc | gzip > ../initramfs.gz
   ```
4. Boot using qemu-system-arm

   ```
   $ qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 200M -kernel $KERNEL/arch/arm/boot/zImage -initrd $BUSYBOX/initramfs.gz -append "root=/dev/ram0"
   ```

The result is this:

[image]

It looks like the kernel does not recognize the file system, but I don't know how to fix that. These are basically the exact steps that every single tutorial follows. There is no such thing as a "cpiofs" to enable in the kernel source.

Comment: It looks like the kernel cannot find the MEDIA the rootfs is on. I am familiar with the 4.x kernel more than the 2.6... Here is a line from my notes `qemu-system-arm -M versatileab -m 128M -kernel zImage -initrd rootfs.img.gz -append "root=/dev/ram rdinit=/bin/sh"` Note the `root=/dev/ram`. Check that `RD_GZIP=Y` in kernel menuconfig for compressed cpio support, or what ever compression you want to use. If you do not need a separate cpio file for your rootfs, include it in your zImage. Point the `INITRAMFS_SOURCE` in menuconfig to the _install folder of busybox.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using 2.6 vs. a newer kernel? In my experience there have been some fixes for the armv5 in the newer kernel.

Comment: It doesn't HAVE to be a 2.6. I am just working towards trying to run it on some older HTC Android hardware which happens to be 2.6. I have also tried a 3.2 kernel with the same result. RD_GZIP=y.

Comment: Also, if i use "root=ram" or "root=ram0" the error message is the same, but "root=ram1" changes the error to "unknown-block(1,1)". Ie: the block minor number changes with the parameter's ramdisk number.

Comment: I believe the unknown block() means that the kernel cannot find the block device (the ram disk). No disk no rootfs. I assume you mean `root=/dev/ram` and `root=/dev/ram0`.

Comment: I do suggest that you try to include your rootfs in the zImage because you do not need to point to the disk, just the init. `qemu-system-arm -M versatileab -m 128M -kernel zImage -append "rdinit=/bin/sh"` (I think, its been a couple of months)

Comment: look at the section "What is initramfs?" here for information, but note that I had to point my kernel to the _install directory from busybox NOT the cpio file I created as instructed here. This is more of a what is the difference between ramDisk and initramfs than a correct how to. Here is another one.

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt

Comment: http://www.stlinux.com/howto/initramfs

Comment: Please copy-paste the text from the terminal. Don't post a screenshot of text, it's hard to read and impossible to search.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a graphical terminal and I cannot select the text. I know there is a way to get that output on stdio, but I haven't been able to figure that out either. I am a QEMU n00b. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success!

The solution, as suggested, was to embed the initrd image into the kernel by pointing CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE to my BusyBox's "_install" directory. Many thanks to jc__ for that tip.

Also, for anyone else trying this, it is worthy of note that I needed to create in the Busybox _install directory:

- dev/console
- dev/loop0

as mentioned in this:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt